# PostgreSQL CRUD functions generator

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Does anyone know if there is an option to autogenerate the create, read, update and delete (CRUD) functions (PL/pgSQL) from a table in pgAdmin?

Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m coding this: https://github.com/ignacioinnovo/PostgresqlAutogeneration

Perhaps it´s useful for anyone!